# Можно ли в этом предложении вместо двоеточия поставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, бсп

Я доверяю любящим: они великодушны.

Answer (score 1):

**Рассуждения на тему вопроса с уже полученными ответами**

**Я доверяю любящим: они великодушны.**

**Можно ли в этом предложении вместо двоеточия поставить запятую?** Да легко! Можно даже тире поставить, и  Вас обязательно поймут правильно: любовь возвышает людей, делает их благородными и достойными доверия.

Цитата: **"...с помощью разных знаков препинания нового смысла (в этом случае) мы не получим".**

**А как же выбрать?**

**Смысл**  сходный: мы одну и ту же мысль или поясняем, или распространяем. **Интонация**  тоже сходная во все случаях, только паузы немного разные. **А графика** – на ваш художественный вкус и стиль вашего текста.

**А как же правила?** А правила как  законы, толковать их можно свободно, всё от "судьи" зависит. Вот интересная пословица: Закон — что паутина: шмель проскочит, а муха увязнет. Три этих знака в БСП законами (правилами)  прописаны, так что выбор за вами.

**Но правила же надо объяснить!**  Здесь всё зависит от того, кому вы объясняете (ситуация дипломатическая). Варианты следующие: от "так У Розенталя сказано, могу показать" до проведения структурно-граммтического анализа предложений. Смотря в чем вы сильны.

**И вывод**

Анализ был проведен user Sibilla, но длинно,  растянуто, и обращен он был к академической аудитории. В результате – 0 баллов.

**Поэтому начинать ответ  надо ... с ответа** (краткого, ясного и даже в какой-то мере эмоционального). А потом уже объяснять и доказывать сказанное.

Это принцип инфостиля: **сразу заинтересовать потенциального читателя**, пока он "не отложил" вас в сторону.

Тогда вас, **возможно**,  будут читать и, **может быть**,  ставить галочки.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. **Я доверЯю лЮбящим -  они великодУшны.**

Вариант 2. **Я доверЯю лЮбящим, они великодУшны.**

Вторая часть **распространяет первую**, в обоих случаях нисходяще-нисходящая интонация с полным понижением голоса в конце каждой части. Это присоединительная интонация, которая может обозначаться **запятой или присоединительным тире.**

На неоднородность (взаимообусловленность) частей  указывает местоимение "они" в качестве структурного элемента.

При постановке **двоеточия** другая интонация: **Я доверяю лЮбящим: они великодУшны.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (могут ли знаки препинания изменить смысл данного высказывания)

**Семантика высказывания** такова: я любящим доверяю, потому что считаю их великодушными. Связь **однонаправленная**: следствие - причина. Нельзя сказать: я им доверяю, **поэтому** они великодушны.

Из этого делаем вывод, что с помощью разных знаков препинания **нового смысла мы не получим,**  а получим только разные интонационно-логические формы  для изложения одного и того же  содержания.

**Двоеточием** четко обозначаем **направление связи**, с помощью присоединительного (не разделителного!) **тире подчеркиваем  взаимообусловленность** частей предложения, а с помощью запятой обозначаем их **неоднородность (опять же взаимосвязанность**), местоимение "они" помогает нам в этом.

ВЕЛИКОДУШИЕ, -я; ср. Наличие высоких душевных качеств; щедрость души, благородство, снисходительность. Проявить в. В порыве великодушия.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от контекста, в котором озвучено это предложение. Для того, чтобы понять разницу, можно задать вопрос и ответить на него.

1. -А  **Вы** доверяете любящим?
      -[да ] **Я** доверяю любящим - [потому что] они великодушны.
2. -Вы **доверяете** любящим [за что именно]?
   -Я **доверяю** любящим: **они великодушны**.
3. -Вы доверяете **любящим** [а не кому-то другому]?
   -Я  доверяю **любящим** [потому], [что] **они** великодушны.

   **Допустимы** все три знака препинания, каждый -  **в своём контексте**. Таким образом, Вы **можете** вместо двоеточия поставить запятую, но смысл предложения тогда изменится.

Answer (score 0):

Разница в нюансах смысла:

"Я доверяю любящим, они великодушны" - Я им доверяю, это связано с тем, что они великодушны.

"Я доверяю любящим: они великодушны" - Я им доверяю именно потому, что они великодушны.

"Я доверяю любящим - они великодушны" - Я им доверяю, потому что они великодушны.

Comment: Так, понятно: интонация, смысл

Comment: А что с распространенностью?

Comment: А в этом предложений как выбрать между двоеточием и запятой?

Comment: "Народы знают: правда есть".

Comment: @Rayn Char  Оформите это, пожалуйста, как отдельный вопрос.